# Read value from combobox and bind to a object property WPF Xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, .net-4.5

In my program I open a new window, this window gets a "Task" object.
The Task has different propertys.
The data context is set to this object.

I have implemented the task object with the  INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

I can bind my normal textbox to the name property of the task, that works fine.

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox_Task_Name" Text="{Binding Path=TaskSpecification.Task_Spec_Name, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="148,50,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

But now here comes my problem:

1. I would like to add comboboxes to the window. ok!
2. The combobox should display some predefined values, could also be through binding. Ok!
3. I want to set the e.g. "Task.Task_Type" to the value of the combobox(with binding) How can I do this with bindings? (Solved)
4. When I load a existing task object, my window should automaticaly display the value of the "Task.Task_Type" object in the combobox. How can I do this?(Solved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I created a new Observablecollection in my task class and did this in my xaml code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox_Task_Type" ItemsSource="{Binding Task_Type_Elements}" SelectedItem="{Binding Task_Type}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="148,147,0,0" Width="120" VerticalAlignment="Top">
```